# What's the purpose of /etc/sysconfig/network file?

Tags: networking, centos

I am using CentOS 6.7.

What's the purpose of `/etc/sysconfig/network` file?

I have found that the first thing `/etc/init.d/network` does is checking if that file exists and exit if it is not founded.

My CentOS 6.7 didn't have that file by default. Why?

Comment: are you using centos 6.7 in your desktop with dhcp?

Comment: @c4f4t0r yes. I am trying to config DHCP with `ONBOOT=yes`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you *really* need it for is setting the hostname. Otherwise, you can add some network and gateway settings, but you can just as easily put that stuff in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX files.